# Angular 5 - Why is my input property undefined?

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular5 and searched for hours but couldn't resolve my issue.
Every related threads on SO are not in the same version as me.

I have an input on which I want to trigger a function when something is typed in that input.

Here's my input:

```
<input
   #autocompleteInput
   class="inputHeader"
   (click)="openSearch()"
   placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
/>
```

Here's my input property declaration:

```
@Input() autocompleteInput: string;
```

When I `console.log(this.autocompleteInput);` in the ngOnInit() method, it display "undefined".

What am I doing wrong ?

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: There is not an initialization in this example.

Comment: You should use @ViewChild if you want to get reference to the input field.

Comment: @iamjc015 you're right, now I get the input. But the main problem is that the input event is not triggered when i type on the input.

Answer (score 2):

Input property is used for component interaction. Here if you want to get the value you entered in input, then you can use

**in html:**

```
 <input
       #autocompleteInput
       class="inputHeader"
       (click)="openSearch()"
       placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
       (input)="inputData($event.target.value)"
    />
```

**in ts:**

```
inputData(data: any) {
 console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: Already tried it, input, keyup, or change events are never triggering.

Comment: Ok. Can you share your code so that I can have a look?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "keyup" event for the same:

```
<input
   #autocompleteInput
   class="inputHeader"
   (click)="openSearch()"
   placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
   (keyup)="methodName($event)"

/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but that's not working :/

Comment: can you share your code with https://stackblitz.com so that I can have better understanding?

Answer (score 1):

`autocompleteInput` is a reference to your `input` element, and not the content of your input.
You would have to use it with the `ViewChild` decorator to get an `ElementRef`:

```typescript
@ViewChild('autocompleteInput') inputRef: ElementRef;
```

From this `ElementRef`, you can get the native element (HTMLInputElement) with `inputRef.nativeElement`.

**However, if you want to get the text as it is typed in the input**, you should use the `input` event:

```html
<input
   #autocompleteInput
   type="text"
   class="inputHeader"
   (input)="onInput($event.target.value)"
   placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
/>
```

```typescript
onInput(value: string) {
  // do something with value
}
```

Or use an `ngModel` to control the value of your input:

```html
<input
   #autocompleteInput
   type="text"
   class="inputHeader"
   [ngModel]="value"
   (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)"
   placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
/>
```

```typescript
value: string;

valueChanged(value: string) {
  this.value = value;
  // do something with this.value
}
```

> See [this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-text-binding)

If you are using Ionic, you should use `<ion-input>` instead of `<input>`:

```
<ion-input type="text" (input)="onInput($event.target.value)"></ion-input>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I already went trying this soution, but the problem is that the input event is never triggered. Do you know what could cause this please ?

Comment: This is a strange issue, could share your code via a stackblitz ?

Comment: For sure, wait plz

Comment: @Pierrick Martellière, I provided a short stackblitz demo to my answer

Comment: Could this come form the ```<div
    [@openCloseSearchList]="openedSearch ? 'open' : 'closed'"
    class="searchResults"
  >
    <div class="searchResultsInput">
      <input
        class="inputHeader"
        placeholder="Coupe homme, lissage brésilen, ..."
      />
      <i class="fas fa-times" (click)="openSearch()"></i>
    </div>
  </div>``` ?

Comment: @Pierrick Martellière, your stackblitz is not working, could you fix it so I can see the input ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? You can't access it ?

Comment: I can access it but it is not running, your page is using ionic and is not included in the app.module.ts Could you produce a minimal example reproducing  the problem ?

Comment: Okay I'll fix it

Comment: I think, your problem is that you are using Ionic and not using ion-input

Comment: Hum nice guess, I'll explore this.

Comment: @Pierrick Martellière, can you provide a working Ionic demo with stackblitz ?

Comment: I'm so stupid, there's a second input in the bottom of my html page that is used when the first input is clicked....

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and patience and sorry for your time lol

Comment: @Pierrick Martellière, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

In ts file

```
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

export class tsClass implements OnInit  {
@ViewChild('autocompleteInput') autocompleteInput;
//now you can user it
this.autocompleteInput = this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement;
}
```

Comment: Right, thanks, but the main problem is that (input), (change) or (keyup) events are not triggered :/

Comment: One question only if not solved yet,
you want input because html is in different component right?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there was another input in the bottom of my template that was used when the first input was clicked. The input event now triggers well.

Sorry for my stupidity and thanks to everyone for the time and patience.